# Absolute value and credit card balance

Tags: absolute-value

I'm embarrassed to ask this question, but my child has the following homework question:

"Use absolute value to describe the relationship between a negative credit card balance and the amount owed."

I'm not sure for what it is they're looking.  Clearly a `-$25` balance means you have `$25` credit. However, the absolute value of `-$25` is `$25`, and positive balances are money you owe.

Is there a simple formula describing this relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a -\$25 balance does not mean you have \$25 credit but that you owe \$25, the absolute value of -\$25.

Comment: I think I see your point.  If you start with a zero balance and charge `$25`, the credit card company will record it on their books as `-$25`.  However, the statement they issue you will show `|-$25| ` or `$25`.  On the other hand if you pay to much and have say a `+$50` balance on their books, their statement will show you have a `-$50` balance, so I'm not sure how that fits.

Comment: The question starts off that you have a negative balance, so the amount you owe is the absolute value. Paying the credit card company is not part of the question

Answer (score 0):

The absolute value of the credit card balance is exactly the amount of money owed